# queue a azure pipeline yaml stage to execute at specific datetime

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have a multistage release pipeline which targets all environments like dev->int->qa->prod-staging slot.
For final swaping of slot we have a requirement to to run at specified datetime during non-business hrs.
How can we delay a specific stage of multi stage yaml to run at certain datetime.

Comment: Here is the details to have scheduled releases https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops if this what you need I can post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Though I agree with the idea of Hany, but the link he shared is about the Release which configured with UI. It does not suitable for your multi-stage YAML pipeline.*

Since what you are using is **multi-stage YAML** pipeline, you can check below sample to configure the corresponding schedule trigger into your YAML.

For example, here is the schedule which make the YAML pipeline run at **Sunday weekly**:

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 12 * * 0"
  displayName: Build on Sunday weekly
  branches:
    include:
    - releases/*
  always: true
```

For `0 12 * * 0`, it is following the syntax of:

```
mm HH DD MM DW
 \  \  \  \  \__ Days of week
  \  \  \  \____ Months
   \  \  \______ Days
    \  \________ Hours
     \__________ Minutes
```

I saw you said you want this pipeline run during non-business hours, so you can focus on the last field `DW`(Days of week). It's available value it `0~6` and **starting with Sunday**.Or you can input with like `Sun`:

```
"0 12 * * Sun"
```

Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers-evaluation) for more details.

Comment: Can this use CRON schedule at stage level, or do we need to use a separate build to use this schdule trigger. What if developer want to pass this datetime value for prod-swap as build queue time parameter.

Comment: @Sanjeev, this schedule work for pipeline level not stage level. Because it in fact is a special trigger way. Do not need to configure it with a new separate build, just put this definition onto the YAML pipeline which you want it run at some special time.

Comment: @Sanjeev what does prod-swap mean? You mean pass datatime value dynamically by using parameters or varibles?

Comment: i meant by this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#swap-two-slots

Comment: Yes, if i pass the datetime at parameter and build initiate at that date and time.

Comment: @Sanjeev, when you configure this schedule time, you must give it hard code value. We does not support pass parameters or variables to **corn**.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT thanks for your answer. I have one question here I have gone through Ms docs and their they saying "The time zone for cron schedules is UTC," So Do I need to make any change in my scheduler I want to schedule 9 pm PST. schedules:
- cron:  "0 21 * * Mon-Fri"
  displayName: Daily rollback build
  always:  true                                                                                                               is this work or do I need to convert according to UTC to PST.

Comment: @GauravJoshi, you must convert the scheduler from PST to UTC, **0 5 * * Tue-Sat**

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Thank you.

Comment: @MerlinLiang I'm not sure your response answer's the OP's question? I'm in a similar situation. Our pipeline already has a cron job to build at midnight. And the release pipeline is listening for the "Schedule" tag. There's a specific stage in the release pipeline, however, that should only run at 8:00 PM, the evening after the midnight pipeline is created.
So, how exactly can a specific stage be scheduled?